# bootstrap carousel disturbs an overlay on some pages

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

i have made a template having almost hundred pages. On some of the blog pages the bootstrap carousel disturbs the header of the page.
Whenever the carousel slides, the overlay of the header disappears somewhere for some seconds and then comes back.

Visit http://symmetry.creativecube.pk/full-page-blog-full-width.html

Please help me with this issue that would be a great favor. The same header and carousel are working fine on all other pages except four pages of blog.

```
<div class="row first-div marginN0" style="background-image:url('assets/images/header-12.jpg')"><!-- Cover -->
        <!-- Cover -->
        <div class="" id="first-div-cover"> 
            <div class="page-main-heading">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h1>Blog</h1>
                    <h5>This is some text written under the heading.</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <!-- Cover  -->
    </div>
    <section>
        <div class="row">
            <div class='container portfolio padding100'>
                <h3 class="col-sm-12"><span class="color-grey">04 OCT </span>BEAUTIFULL CAROUSEL IN BLOG</h3>
                <div class="col-sm-12 service-text height-50">  
                  <ul class="blog padding0"> 
                    <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><a href="#">16th February 2015</a>/</li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-comments"></i><a href="#">20</a>/</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Illustrations</a>,<a href="#">Design</a></li>
                  </ul>                               
                </div>
                <div class ="col-sm-12 ">
                    <p>
                        Suspendisse tincidunt eget ipsum non placerat. Donec mattis commodo sapien non pellentesque. Ut convallis magna ut erat iaculis sollicitudin at vel est. In semper odio quis consequat sollicitudin. Cras sed interdum arcu, eget egestas tellus. Donec vitae nisl ut tortor suscipit convallis mattis sed dui. Fusce interdum neque quis mattis volutpat. Morbi accumsan fermentum eros eu blandit. Vestibulum sem elit, varius sed lectus eget, vehicula dignissim nunc. Cras bibendum erat ut dolor convallis, a ornare odio vehicula. Sed blandit, massa in pulvinar fermentum, metus diam sodales mauris, quis vestibulum lectus odio ut est.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 padding50">
                    <article class='portfolio-items'>
                        <div class="row marginN0">
                            <div id='myCarousel' class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <!-- Indicators -->
                                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                                </ol>

                                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                    <div class="item active">
                                        <a class="zoom-picture n1" href="assets/images/blog/BL5.jpg">
                                            <img alt="image" src="assets/images/blog/BL5.jpg">
                                        </a>
                                    </div> 

                                    <div class="item">
                                        <a class="zoom-picture n1" href="assets/images/blog/BL1.jpg">
                                            <img alt="image" src="assets/images/blog/BL5.jpg">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <a class="zoom-picture n1" href="assets/images/blog/BL15.jpg">
                                            <img alt="image" src="assets/images/blog/BL5.jpg">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <a class="zoom-picture n1" href="assets/images/blog/BL2.jpg">
                                            <img alt="image" src="assets/images/blog/BL5.jpg">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                </a>

                                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML in the post?

Comment: The whole document is needed please :)

Comment: can you give me your email ?

Comment: One thing I see: when you delete first OR second carousel, it is working fine, but when two carousels are working bug exist.

Comment: Ok, I think I found it, add `position: relative` to `.first-div`

Comment: Working perfectly now :) Thank You so much :)